# how to assign a condition to an imageView by using if else?

Tags: android, kotlin, if-statement, random

I tried to show a random imageView out of 2(one,two) with this
`binding.imageView.setImageResource(oneandtwo[random.nextInt(oneandtwo.size)])` it works fine
and

i wanted to increase score when i clicked on imageView
but score increases independent to that, sometimes increases when i clicked on imageView2 and sometimes imageView, i want to increase score when i only clicked on imageView. i couldnt figure out. Thanks in advance.

```
    var score = 0
    val oneandtwo: IntArray = intArrayOf(
        R.drawable.ic_baseline_looks_one_24,
        R.drawable.ic_baseline_looks_two_24
    )

binding.imageView.setOnClickListener{
            val random = Random
            binding.imageView.setImageResource(oneandtwo[random.nextInt(oneandtwo.size)])
            if (oneandtwo[random.nextInt(oneandtwo.size)]==(R.drawable.ic_baseline_looks_one_24)){
                score++
                binding.textView.text = score.toString()
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems that both the answers cover - if clicking a particular image is meant to give you points, you have to check the image *before* you change it. And if you're using random items, you need to pick *one* and keep a reference to it. This:

```
binding.imageView.setImageResource(oneandtwo[random.nextInt(oneandtwo.size)])
if (oneandtwo[random.nextInt(oneandtwo.size)]==(R.drawable.ic_baseline_looks_one_24))
```

picks *two completely independent numbers* which *may not match* - and they're supposed to be referencing the same item, right? Get your random thing once, use it twice

---

RahulK's answer should work but here's another way you could do it, with an explicit listener object so you can throw a state variable in there:

```
binding.imageView.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
    // keep track of whether the current image adds to the score when clicked
    var givesPoints = false
            
    override fun onClick(view: View) {
        // first, we just got clicked, so add to the score if appropriate
        if (givesPoints) score++

        // you can just call random() on a collection to get a random element from it
        val resId = oneAndTwo.random()
        // set the image - might be better to do (view as ImageView).setImageResource
        // so it sets it on -whatever was clicked- so it's easier to reuse
        binding.imageView.setImageResource(resId)
        // now set whether this new image gives points or not
        givesPoints = resId == R.drawable.ic_baseline_looks_one_24
    }
})
```

So this way, every time you set a new image, the listener knows whether to give points for it next time it's clicked

---

I don't know how you have this set up, you're only initialising things *when the image is clicked* so if you need to set them up beforehand (so you can have an image displayed that you an click for points) you probably want everything in a separate function you can call when clicked *and* during setup:

```
/** Assigns a random picture to this ImageView - returns true if it's a point-scoring pic */
fun assignRandomPic(imageView: Imageview): Boolean {
    val resId = oneAndTwo.random()
    imageView.setImageResource(resId)
    return resId == R.drawable.ic_baseline_looks_one_24
}
```

```
// set an initial image, storing whether it scores points
val scoreMe = assignRandomPic(binding.imageView)

binding.imageView.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
    // initialise this as appropriate for the image we just set up
    var givesPoints = scoreMe
            
    override fun onClick(view: View) {
        if (givesPoints) score++
        // set a new pic and store its point-scoring state
        givesPoints = assignRandomPic(view as ImageView)
    }
})
```

or you could just do `var givesPoints = assignRandomPic(binding.imageView)` and init the image inside the click listener, whatever feels better

Comment: yes your code is wotking too , thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The number you gave in the image and the number you checked in the if block may not match and will not give the result you want. If you change code like this. Probably your problem will be solved.

```
binding.imageView.setOnClickListener{
        val random = Random().nextInt(oneandtwo.size)
        binding.imageView.setImageResource(oneandtwo[random])
        if (oneandtwo[random]==(R.drawable.ic_baseline_looks_one_24)){
            score++
            binding.textView.text = score.toString()
        }
```

}

Comment: it does same thing, nothing`s changed

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is checking the resourceId of the newly generated image, not the one you just clicked. That's why it not giving the result you want ,i.e, increment on the click of imageView and not on click of imageView2. Try below code. it should work

```
var score = 0
val oneandtwo: IntArray = intArrayOf(R.drawable.ic_baseline_looks_one_24,R.drawable.ic_baseline_looks_two_24)

/*Initalize the initial image and tag either here or in xml file*/
val random = Random().nextInt(oneandtwo.size)
binding.imageView.setImageResource(oneandtwo[random])
binding.imageView.Tag = oneandtwo[random]


binding.imageView.setOnClickListener{

    val imageTag = binding.imageView.Tag
    if (imageTag == (R.drawable.ic_baseline_looks_one_24)) {
       score++
       binding.textView.text = score.toString()
    }
 
    val random = Random().nextInt(oneandtwo.size)
    binding.imageView.setImageResource(oneandtwo[random])
    binding.imageView.Tag = oneandtwo[random]
}
```